# Secure Variables passed to the form

Tags: php, forms, variables, url

I am working on "express checkin form" all it has to do is to check for missing data and ask fro those details you would be asked when arriving to the Hotel so on the Checkin Form basically.
Based on details sent in their email confirmation it will generate hyperlink with image banner Express Checin - Click here or so. This will have url `domain.com/checkin_app.php?&cmd=start_app&t=Mr&n=Matt&s=Smith`

Those parameters passed in url are then encoded with base64 and displayed like

```
domain.com/checkin_app.php?&cmd=start_app&t=TXI=&n=TWF0dA==&s=U21pdGg=
```

it will then go to next function which will display form with those details decoded and it will ask whether you wish to order newspaper, upgrade room, or if second guests details are missing to update those.

On submit all it will do is send only filled in details to the reception for further processing.

What is the best way to secure this type of form or passing of data.

I dont want to store any of those details in database.

Pross and cons and suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without any server-side state whatsoever, you'll pretty much have to use a *signature* scheme. Meaning, all the data must be hashed together with a secret the server has, to produce a signature which you add to everything:

```
...?cmd=...&...&signature=noIYUfbq2158N238nqw...
```

This signature can be checked by repeating the same hash process of the submitted data and the server secret and compared to the provided signature.

The general approach to such a signature would be an HMAC, with the data-to-be-hashed normalised into a specific format, e.g. sorted alphabetically, serialised to a string using JSON, then hashed, so it's a repeatable process.

I'd look into [JWTs](http://jwt.io) as a readymade solution for this. A JWT is a signed data bag which you can use to transport all those values.

Comment: Thank you @deceze, how about if i can use DB but not for their details but some sort of secret key or so?

Comment: Then you should treat it like a session and store all the related data in the database tied to some random id, and just provide that random id to the user.

Comment: so store all data in db and read them from db by secret key or unique id assigned to this data record.

How about this url passing details in first place? can this be done that way at all? so when you click it will immediately add those to DB and then display this id or sec_key?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you transport the data client-side, the client can manipulate the data. Solution: sign it to guard against manipulation. Alternative: give the client just some meaningless id and store the actual data on the server side tied to that id. How exactly you do that is somewhat irrelevant. Again, *sessions* behave like that by default.

Comment: I can only get this details as per what I have described ```domain.com/checkin_app.php?&cmd=start_app&t=Mr&n=Matt&s=Smith``` This is generated by 3rd party software as where Confirmation letter is produced, hence my question.

Comment: `domain.com` is *your app*? And a 3rd party sends visitors directly to that URL? Then you just have to take that as given, there's nothing you can do to verify it.

Comment: domain.com is example? What I am saying is that within this app where email confirmation is prepared and sent we can set image banner with url containing those details, I have no access to this server side of the system so the detials can only be passed to out app that way to be then encrypeted or hashed as per your suggestion?

which part of this you missed as I thought I was clear in first post?

Comment: ‍♂️ I have no idea what we're talking about anymore, sorry…